# Matplotlib axes are crammed with numbers from my data list

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, axis-labels

I want my axes to show the scales that I have picked, and then the hundreds of points be on the graph. Instead I have hundreds of values on the axes and few points on the graph. (The file being read has around 800 values, I only get about 20 points)

```
def read1(file):                
    with open(file,"r") as b: 
        return [i.split()[0] for i in b.readlines()]

def read2(file):                
    with open(file,"r") as theta: 
        return [i.split()[1] for i in theta.readlines()]

def XRD_Analysis(file):
    w = read1(file)
    z = read2(file)
    plt.axis([0,30,0,100])
    plt.show
    plt.plot(w,z,"r.")
    return 

XRD_Analysis("XRD_example1.txt")
```

Comment: You probably want to convert your strings to floats: `return [float(i.split()[0]) for i in ...`